# Why does C not support initializing const variables using an if-else statement?

Tags: c, constants

I want to initialize a `const` variable using an **if-else**.
 For example:

```
const int foo;
if (bar) {
    foo = 1;
} else {
    foo = 2;
}
```

In Java, this is legal code (using `final` instead of `const`). The reason is that in all possible outcomes, the variable is assigned once and never reassigned. In C, this is not legal code. What is the reason that it can't be legal code in C?

Comment: Because initialising a `const` happens at the point of definition, and is performed by the compiler.    Whereas an `if` statement is executed at run time, after all variables are defined.

Comment: Note that `foo = 1;` is not _initialization_.  It is _assignment_, even though it is the first time `foo` is given a value here.  `int foo = 42;` is an example of _initialization_.

Comment: @jhourback I tried to explain the reason why it's not possible, the way I understand it. Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: @Peter Not true, e.g. `const int foo = rand();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator, but keep in mind that for objects with static or thread-local storage class, the initializer expression needs to be a compile-time constant:

```
const int bar =  42;
#define BAR 42

#if 0
    const int foo = bar ? 1 : 2; /*ERROR -- bar is not an integer constant */
#else
    const int foo = BAR ? 1 : 2;
#endif

void fn(void)
{
    const int foo = bar ? 1 : 2;
#if 0
    static const int stc_foo = bar ? 1 : 2; /*ERROR*/
#else
    static const int stc_foo = BAR ? 1 : 2;
#endif
}
```

---

The reason an if-else statement can't be used for the initialization is because allowing it would require some rather extensive changes to the C grammar, and it would possibly make the C grammar and semantics much more complicated.

Basically, instead of simply having to verify that the declarator is followed by `=` and an `initializer` expression and that that initializer expression is a constant, the compiler would have to remember each static/thread-local variable that hasn't been initialized and then look for unconditionally executed compile-time evaluable branches that follow it an assign to it and use them for the initialization.

Furthermore, statements would have to be allowed in file scope (statements are not allowed in file scope in the current C grammar) and verified for constness and memory access limited to writes to translation-unit-local global variables. Alternatively, they could be implicitly turned into global constructors, but that would introduce additional problems such as constructor ordering between compilation units (which would be hard to resolve if the constructor generation were implicit), the need for implementations to support global constructor in the first place, or the blurring of the currently rather straightforward performance characteristics of static variable assignments.

Comment: Eventually the complete answer. I would add as well that the cont variables with the static storage will be placed in RODATA segment - and on many systems they will be protected by the MMU (or will be placed in the flash memory of uC). Automatic `const` variables are stored on the stack or in the uP registers and if are stored on the stack are not protected against unintentional write.

Answer (score 16):

You can initialize the `foo` variable conditionally by means of the *ternary operator*:

`const int foo = bar ? 1 : 2;`

Note that, if `foo` is not an automatic variable, then the initializing expression must be abe to be evaluated at compile-time, otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: but only when `foo` is an `automatic variable`. Otherwise compile error

Comment: @PeterJ - Not really, no. [Rather toyish example](http://ideone.com/zj6DuO)

Comment: @StoryTeller - no - in this example assignment is constant. Is evaluated by the compiler. Very bad example. Expected more when clicked the link

Comment: @PeterJ - A very accurate example, as opposed to your broad and inaccurate statement. You can initialize static const variables just fine, since the ternary operator is a constant expression when all its operands are themselves constant expressions.

Comment: No in the scope of this question.

Comment: @PeterJ - This answer perfectly fits the scope of the question without adding superfluous and wrong details suggested in comments.

Comment: @StoryTeller IMO does not as `bar` in the question can be anything - not necessary the constant expression. `const` used with global or automatic variables has much more implications. for example 1. global scope - the variable is stored in the rodata segment 2. automatic - is not. And it has a very practical meaning.

Comment: @PeterJ - Then I suggest you ask the OP to address your valid concerns. If their example is lacking in your opinion, tell them. This answer is not the proper address for that.

Comment: @StoryTeller your comment is correct only if the whole ternary expression is constant and can be evaluated compile time. This is only one of many possible cases (for variables with the static storage)

Comment: @PeterJ - You are missing the point, and seem to relish in arguing for the sake of arguing. I repeat, ask the OP to clarify if you think their example isn't clear enough. I'm signing off.

Comment: @StoryTeller IMO you are missing and you have started this discussion just to start it.

Answer (score 4):

In C, **const** makes the variable **read-only**.

You can initialize **const** variable only at the time of declaration, not after that as it becomes read-only.

That's why your code is not legal in C, as you are **updating a read-only** variable.

Hope it will help !!